# Swapping Azure Staging/Production environments with a SignalR Hub

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

I have a SignalR service running on an Azure Web Role. I'm interested in deploying a new version of the service, first to Staging and then to the Production deployment slot.

My question is if I swap the two deployment slots while there are existing connections to the service on Production:

What will happen to those existing connections? Will they still be connected to the now-Staging slot, or will they reconnect to the the now-Production slot? Or something else? Is this client-dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same isse in 2020 with swapping BlazorServerSide, beaucse I have an Azure SignalR Service in front of my AppService slots.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on how you're storing SignalR connection information.

If you're using a permanent external storage solution (see [this post](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)), then swapping from one web server to another, which is what the VIP swap will end up doing, shouldn't interrupt the connections.

If you're using a different approach for storing the connection info like in-memory, then it's going to be lost b/c you're going to be transferring client traffic from one web server to another with the deployment swap.